# Kotlin build error for a non nullable variable using let error Unresolved reference: length

Tags: kotlin

gradle 7.4.2

```
fun main() {
    var nullableName: String? = null
    nullableName?.let {
    println(it.length)
    }
}
```

Error message: /Nullables.kt: (30, 20): Unresolved reference: length

Comment: “for a non nullable variable” — what are you claiming to be non-nullable: `it`, or `length`? (Hint: one of those _is_ nullable…)

Comment: what are your imports?

Comment: @gidds ‘it’ should be the nullable

Comment: @sidgate no imports

Comment: @azgcloudev Indeed: `it` is the same type as `nullableName`, i.e. `String?`, so it could be a String or null. And does `null` have a `length` property?